# Error while using ContentScraper in Rcrawler package

Tags: javascript, html, r, web-scraping, rcrawler

I am trying to extract the tables from these pages
(https://spactrack.net/activespacs/ & https://warrants.tech/). I am using Rcrawler package to extract them, but it's throwing me an error when I run the below code.

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(Rcrawler)

#install_browser(version = "2.1.1",
                 baseURL = "https://github.com/wch/webshot/releases/download/v0.3.1/")

LS <- browser_path()

#to extract from the first link

url <- "https://spactrack.net/activespacs/"

table <- ContentScraper(Url = url, 
                 XpathPatterns = c("/html/body/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table"),
                  asDataFrame = TRUE, browser = LS)

#to extract from the second link:

url2 <- "https://warrants.tech/"

table2 <- ContentScraper(Url = url2, 
          XpathPatterns = c("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table"),
          asDataFrame = TRUE, browser = LS)
```

Could you help me extract these tables? Thank you.

Comment: Do you just need these two tables? If so, you can use a real browser to inspect and copy those two HTML table elements. After that, use `read_html` in `rvest` to read the HTML text from clipboard.

Comment: @ekoam: Thank you very much for your help! I was able to copy the HTML table elements and extract them using read_html function. The issue now is I am not able to extract the website link in the fields 'SPAC website' and "SEC filings' from the first link/table. In the second table it copies only 25 rows but there are about 230 in total (if you extend the price range). How do I get this data?

Comment: You need `RSelenium` to get the tables from these webpages